# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCA550A839 in Project1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000002F82CFEF60. occurred

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that use opencv to read pixel value from an image and print that in a console or another window. My program compiled and linked successfully but while runing the program in Visual stdio I get following line of error.

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCA550A839 in Project1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000002F82CFEF60. occurred"

I have already tried to run the executable directly . Then i get this error message "Debug error. about() has been called".
Here is my code of main.cpp

'''c++

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <SDL.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

using namespace cv;

int retColorRed(int x, int y)
{
    Mat img = imread("s1.jpg", 0);
    return img.at<Vec3d>(x, y)[0];
}

int retColorGreen(int x, int y)
{
    Mat img = imread("s1.jpg", 0);
    return img.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
}

int retColorBlue(int x, int y)
{
    Mat img = imread("s1.jpg", 0);
    return img.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
}



    #define WINDOW_WIDTH 200
    #define WINDOW_HEIGHT 300

    int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        SDL_Window* window;

        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0,&window, &renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);


        int width = WINDOW_WIDTH;
        int height = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        int horizonaltIter = 0, virticalIter = 0;

        while (virticalIter <= height)
        {
            while (horizonaltIter <= width) {
                int red = retColorRed(horizonaltIter,virticalIter);
                int green = retColorGreen(horizonaltIter, virticalIter);
                int blue = retColorBlue(horizonaltIter, virticalIter);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, red, green, blue, 255);
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, horizonaltIter, virticalIter);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
                horizonaltIter++;
            }
            virticalIter++;
        }



        while (1) {
            if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                break;
        }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

'''

this is the error message that show in Visual studio ide

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCA550A839 in Project1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000000A6BD0FF1A0. occurred"

Comment: It seems the heap has been corrupted. That means you may have written beyond allocated memory (malloc).

Comment: I don't see you check whether `imread` succeeded.

Comment: ... and if adding the check @PaulOgilvie suggests doesn't help, use the debugger and step through the program until it crashes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie found it , it was my dll which causing the problem .. thanks

Comment: @Adrian yes, it would be width instead of height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `while (horizonaltIter <= height) {` to `while (horizonaltIter <= width) {` and it should work!

Comment: yes , but the bad allocation was caused by the dll. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK, so it wasn't just the `height/width` error. If it was, the question will probably get close as a typo. I'm just being greedy for points! :)

Comment: If you are happy, just leave it. If the 'big boys' want to close it, they will! I'm also quite new, here. When you accept the answer, I get points; if it gets closed, I lose them again! But it's no problem, really. But now you can also "upvote" my answer (I think) - even more pretty points for me!